# Launch javascript bookmarklet in Android webview on Android button cick

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a bookmarklet that is normally fired with:

```
javascript: function loadScript(scriptURL) {
var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); 
scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript'); 
scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL); 
document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
} loadScript('http:/www.pathtojavascript.co.uk/javascript.min.js');
```

from a bookmark.

I am now trying to get this fired in an Android app, I have a webview and an Android button below the webview, what I am trying to do is load the bookmarklet into the webview when the Android button is pressed.

I have been looking at http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

However this I think is used when the javascript is in the html file that is loaded in the webview, while mine is to appear above the current webpage and the javascript is found at  `http:/www.pathtojavascript.co.uk/javascript.min.js`

My current class:

```
public class SearchViewer extends SherlockActivity {

    TextView grabit;
    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchviewer);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrowleft);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        setTitle(name);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
        grabit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grabit);
        grabit.setOnClickListener(OnClick_grabit);


    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
             break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this); 
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
      }


    private OnClickListener OnClick_grabit = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Code to launch javascript?
        }
    };



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to launch Javascript

```
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:$the method to be invoked$");
```

Replace **$the method to be invoked$** with the javascript method that you would like to invoke. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:VODPlay()");
           }
        });
```

This way, you can call a specific function in the js file.